# CoreData: Can't modify an immutable model

Tags: ios, core-data

Here's my code

```
__managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

NSArray *entities = [__managedObjectModel entities];
for (NSEntityDescription *entityDesc in entities)
{
    NSLog(@"TWEAK");
    [entityDesc setProperties:[entityDesc properties]];
}
```

this throw exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Can't modify an immutable model.' on

I don't know why? in my oppinion this should be editable yet, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2):

The official [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/NSEntityDescription.html) says that it's editable **until the managed object model is associated to a persistent store coordinator**.

Therefore:

1. If you assigned the mom to a psc in the code you didn't quote in the question, then it's as described in the doc.
2. If you really just run the code pasted above, it's a bug on the part of Apple, either the library or its documentation. You should file a bug report.

Anyway, a CoreData database file is associated to a fixed model, so usually you can't just tweak an entity description in a model and use it against your saved CoreData file. What do you want to achieve by tweaking the entity description?

Comment: Actually it looks like a bug in iOS 5, since it working as described in iOS 4. [model copy] return editable copy that can be "tweaked".